# R Plotly Rangeslider covers tick-labels - Is it possible to set location of Rangeslider?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I´m using the Plotly package in R to make a plot with both a rangeslider and rangeselector.

The problem is that the rangeslider tends to cover the x-axis tick labels.

A solution could be to manually set the location of the rangeslider, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do that.

Below you find a minimal working example of the problem together with a picture of it.

```
# Make Some Data: 
Dates = as.POSIXct(c("2017-08-08 00:00")) + (0:71)*60^2
Values = rep_len(mtcars$mpg, 72)
tb =  dplyr::tibble(Values, Dates)

# Plot
p = tb %>% plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = 'markers', x = ~Dates, y = ~Values) %>% 
            layout(xaxis = list(
              rangeslider = list(type = "date"),
              rangeselector = list(
                buttons = list(list(step = "all", label = "All")))
              ))
p
```

[image: "Note how some of the dates are covered"]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Cheers,

Comment: Strange, the same code gives me a plot where there is no overlap. Are all your packages up-to-date? Is this a screenshot from a shiny app - possibly some strange CSS?

Comment: Nope, it is a screenshot from the build-in viewer (maximized) in RStudio, but the same happens when I use Shiny. I downloaded all packages yesterday directly from GitHub, so there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: So you have installed the dev versions? Maybe install the packages from CRAN instead.

Comment: I checked and see this problem in R and Rstudio, but if I reduce progressively the height of the window, the overlapping at some point disappear.

Comment: Installing the packages from CRAN didn't solve the problem. As @MarcoSandri mentions it is possible to make the overlapping disappear by progressively reduce the height of the window. Problem is that in the end I´m going to use the plot in Shiny where it isn't possible for the user to reduce the height of the window. :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By messing around with various options/settings, I found that increasing the tick lengths and let the ticks appear on the inside of x-axis rather than on the outside solved my problem.

See the code below for an example

```
# Make Some Data: 
Dates = as.POSIXct(c("2017-08-08 00:00")) + (0:71)*60^2 
Values = rep_len(mtcars$mpg, 72)
tb =  dplyr::tibble(Values, Dates)

# Plot
p = tb %>% plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = 'markers', x = ~Dates, y = ~Values) %>% 
        layout(xaxis = list(ticks = "inside", ticklen = 10,
          rangeslider = list(type = "date", thickness=0.1),
          rangeselector = list(
            buttons = list(list(step = "all", label = "All")))
          ))
p
```

However, this is a hacker solution, and I´m still on the lookout for a method to set the position of the rangeslider.

Answer (score 1):

Try to solve the overlapping problem tuning the `thickness` parameter of `rangeslider`:

```
# Make Some Data: 
Dates = as.POSIXct(c("2017-08-08 00:00")) + (0:71)*60^2
Values = rep_len(mtcars$mpg, 72)
tb =  dplyr::tibble(Values, Dates)

# Plot
p = tb %>% plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = 'markers', x = ~Dates, y = ~Values) %>% 
            layout(xaxis = list(
              rangeslider = list(type = "date", thickness=0.3),
              rangeselector = list(
                buttons = list(list(step = "all", label = "All")))
              ))
p
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help.

Comment: @JeppeS. Strange. This trick solved the problem on my R and Rstudio. Have you tried with thickness = 0.1, 0.2, etc ?

Comment: Yes, it seemed to work but when I maximized the window the problem was  there again. However the solution I posted below seems to work in either case.